# How do I get the actual object created by FrameworkElementFactory?

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelementfactory

I am using the following code to create a draggable control by adding a template control to the Thumb.  However I need to call methods on the FilePickerPopup object that gets created in order to set delegates etc.  How can I access the object that gets created ?  The method shown below fails to get the actual object.

Is there a simpler method to create a draggable UserControl than this ?  As I understand it this may be a deprecated method anyway.  Thanks.

```
filePicker = new Thumb();

ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate();

var filePickerControl = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Controls.Popups.FilePickerPopup));

filePickerControl.Name = "FilePickerControl";

template.VisualTree = filePickerControl;

filePicker.Template = template;

FilePickerPopup fpp = filePicker.Template.FindName("FilePickerControl", filePicker) as FilePickerPopup;

fpp.SetParent(parent);
```

Note that the FilePickerPopup has a public method SetParent(object parent);

Comment: That appears to be an entirely different question.

Comment: Oops, my mistake wrong link pasted.